# Does the click event mutate the source json in this D3 example?

Tags: d3.js

I don't understand what the **click** event does in this [d3 collapsible tree](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083) example. Is it modifying the original **root** JSON data structure. It seems, does that indicate the node data structure point to the source data structure (**root**) instead of creating a copy of **root** and using the copy (immutability)?

```
var i = 0,
    duration = 750,
    root;
```

...

```
// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's modifying `root` and not a copy of it as the `d` passed to `click` is just a reference into `root`. You can test that if you add a `console.log(root);` at the end of `click`.

Here's what gets logged after clicking on the root node 4 times:

```
Object { name: "flare", x0: 380, y0: 0, depth: 0, x: 380, y: 0, id: 11, _children: Array[10] }
Object { name: "flare", x0: 380, y0: 0, depth: 0, x: 380, y: 0, id: 11, _children: null, children: Array[10] }
Object { name: "flare", x0: 380, y0: 0, depth: 0, x: 380, y: 0, id: 11, _children: Array[10] }
Object { name: "flare", x0: 380, y0: 0, depth: 0, x: 380, y: 0, id: 11, _children: null, children: Array[10] }
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Dogbert/Ltkgwd06/